# How to generate crash report of application?

Tags: c, arm, rtos, ds-5

Currently i am using `ARM DS-5 IDE` for development the application for one arm based target device and for compilation `ARM Compiler tool chain RVCT3.1` used. 
Thread X RTOS used in target device.

After loading application in target device, it will crash accidentally after some time.So i want to know where it crash. There for i need stack dump or trace of it.

Using AT command on target hardware some i am able to generate stack dump, as below

```
+XLOG: Exception Number: 1
 Trap Class: 0xBBBB ()
 System Stack: 
  0x00000022
  0x502637BC
  0x01000022
  0x00016001
  0xC9FFDF00
  0x000022C1
  0x50310CC0
  0x000022C1
  0x00000049
  0x5025D740
  0x00000002
  0x00000000
  0x680DCF6E
  0x00FF22C0
  0x49F70301
  0x6A552FFB
  0xB104FF3D
  0xCA9895C1
  0x46F4EBA7
  0xAC73DDEA
Date: 2000:1:1
 Time: 0:54:10
 Register:
 r0:  0x00000022  r1:  0x502637BC  r2:  0x01000022
 r3:  0x00016001  r4:  0xC9FFDF00  r5:  0x000022C1
 r6:  0x50310CC0  r7:  0x000022C1  r8:  0x00000049
 r9:  0x5025D740  r10:  0x00000002  r11:  0x00000000
 r12:  0x680DCF6E  r13:  0xFFFF3598  r14:  0x920C10C4
 r15:  0x00FF22C0
 SPSR: 0x80000073  DFAR:  0x00000000  DFSR: 0x00000000
+XLOG: Exception Number: 2
 Trap Class: 0xAAAA ()
 System Stack: 
  0x00000000
  0x5029FC8D
  0x502637C0
  0x00000000
  0xC6FFBF00
  0x000022C1
  0x50310CC0
  0x000022C1
  0x00000049
  0x5025D740
  0x00000002
  0x00000000
  0x5A067AAE
  0x50210B2C
  0x49F70301
  0x6A552FFB
  0xB104FF3D
  0xCA9895C1
  0x46F4EBA7
  0xAC73DDEA
Date: 2000:1:1
 Time: 1:33:6
 Register:
 r0:  0x00000000  r1:  0x5029FC8D  r2:  0x502637C0
 r3:  0x00000000  r4:  0xC6FFBF00  r5:  0x000022C1
 r6:  0x50310CC0  r7:  0x000022C1  r8:  0x00000049
 r9:  0x5025D740  r10:  0x00000002  r11:  0x00000000
 r12:  0x5A067AAE  r13:  0xFFFF3598  r14:  0x920C10C4
 r15:  0x50210B2C
 SPSR: 0x80000053  DFAR:  0xC6FFBF04  DFSR: 0x00000005
```

How can i use this dump to debug issue? how can i find address using map file?

Comment: Does your target hardware have a MMU?  Do you have a hardware debugger interface like JTAG?  If the answers to both are 'no', then you have a big problem.

Comment: You can easily add debugging output printed through a serial port, or if the hardware have a dedicated debug-port or JTAG interface you could connect a debugger to that. Because the problems with real-time operating systems is that they often run on systems with limited space and functionality, and a crash-dump is big and may be slow to generate.

Comment: @MartinJames It doesn't have JTAG interface.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg As a first try i tried same (use debug print) thing as you think, but it's not help much about this.

Comment: If you have two debug printouts, and you only get the first, then you know that the crash happens between the two printouts. Then narrow it down from there, closing the gaps between the two printouts until a single function call, and then continue narrowing it down inside the function until you find the offending line. When inside a single function, printing the values of the function arguments as well as the values of local variables helps, to find e.g. null or other invalid pointers or array indexes out of bounds.,

Comment: ^^^ essentially, hard work.  Rebuilds, prints, taking notes, analysing..

Comment: protip - don't take on embedded without a hardware debugger interface, especially with a tasker kernel.  It will drive you insane.